# how can I open emoji keyboard in React Native without using 3rd Party Library?

Tags: react-native

how can I open emoji keyboard in React Native without using 3rd Party Library ?

```js
<TextInput 
  onChangeText={e => handleChange("message", e)} 
  keyboardType={"default"} 
/>
```

Comment: have you seen this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71806158/how-to-open-emoji-keyboard-instead-of-alphabets-using-textinput-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can't. React Native based on native applications. This means that you can't do something you can't do in native.

There are 2 answers to this problem on both platforms.

For IOS: [Call emoji keyboard programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585254/call-emoji-keyboard-programmatically)

For Android [Android : How to programmatically open the soft keyboard in Emoji View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013723/android-how-to-programmatically-open-the-soft-keyboard-in-emoji-view)

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide any public API for that, I created a small library that open modal for a user to choose emoji from [react-native-emojis-picker](https://github.com/Majiedo/react-native-emojis-picker)